# Firefox doesn't play animated gif properly (works fine in Chrome)

Tags: javascript

I have an animated gif image that gets swapped to another animated gif onclick. So far everything works. But when I want to make another change (to a third animated gif) then firefox wont play the third gif animation at all. In Chrome it works fine.

I uploaded a test file so you can see for your self:

http://fastertutorials.com/stuff/test.html

In firefox, when you click on the smiley it will start spinning. But if you click a second time then it should explode. But the explosion never plays in firefox, only in Chrome.

Comment: what version of ff are you using?

Comment: Works for me in Firefox 14 beta.

Comment: No need to use `.getAttribute()` to get the "src" of the element. The "src" attribute becomes a **property** of the DOM element object, so you can just reference ".src". That works in all browsers.

Comment: Reproduced in Firefox 13. I do get the "explosion" animation in IE 8 though.

Comment: 13.0.1 reproduced, if i click soon after the face turning green it explodes but if i wait a while then it just turns sad - What an awesome way to test by the way! I ended up watching the animation a few times completely forgetting about this question.

Comment: I'm on firefox 12, I will update now to test in ff 13.

Comment: Okay it seems to work fine in Firefox 14 beta!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost certainly a bug in Firefox 12 and 13, but luckily it appears to be fixed in 14.

Stragely, having another instance of the image present seems to fix the problem. A possible (but very hacky) workaround might be to add another instance of `polly.gif` to the bottom of the page and set its `height` and/or `width` to 0. Setting `display` to `none` doesn't work.

You can try the workaround here: http://jsfiddle.net/tH5TC/

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be a firebug error.
try this:

1. open firebug
2. load page
3. click on image twice
4. If you get a static sad face open firebug html console
5. Open the `<body>` tag
6. hover over the image tag's `id`

The animation should then start to play.

Comment: I was able to duplicate the bug on a fresh install of Firefox 13 without Firebug.